# OCI runtime create failed: runc create failed: unable to start container process: exec: "split_csv.py": executable file not found in $PATH: unknown

Tags: docker

**My dockerfile**

```
FROM python:latest

#ENTRYPOINT [ "python split_csv.py -i test_data.csv -o test_data.csv -r 100" ]

WORKDIR /docker_task2

ENV PORT 80

COPY split_csv.py ./docker_task2

ADD test_data.csv ./docker_task2


COPY . /docker_task2//

CMD ["python", "split_csv.py", "test_data.csv"]
```

**My code**

```
docker run splitter split_csv.py -i test_data.csv -o test_data.csv -r 100
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

When you start the container

```bash
docker run splitter \
  split_csv.py -i test_data.csv -o test_data.csv -r 100
```

it tries to look up the command `split_csv.py` in the `$PATH` environment variable, following the normal Unix rules.  You've copied your script into the `/docker_task2` directory in the image, which is also the current directory, and you need to explicitly specify the path since the directory isn't one of the default `$PATH` locations like `/usr/bin`.

```bash
docker run splitter \
  ./split_csv.py ...
```

This is also subject to the other normal Unix rules here: the script must be executable (run `chmod +x split_csv.py` on your host system if it isn't, and commit that permission change to source control) and it must begin with a "shebang" line `#!/usr/bin/env python3` as the very first line of the file.

Having fixed this, you also don't need to repeat the `python` interpreter in your image's `CMD`.  You can probably simplify the Dockerfile significantly:

```bash
FROM python:latest
WORKDIR /docker_task2

# Install Python library dependencies first; saves time on rebuild
# COPY requirements.txt ./
# RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

# Copy the entire context directory ./ to the current directory ./
COPY ./ ./

# Set defaults to run the image
ENV PORT 80
CMD ["./split_csv.py", "-i", "test_data.csv"]
```