# Spiffe error while deploying client-agent pods

Tags: kubernetes, amazon-eks, sleep, spiffe

I am using this guide for deploying Spiffe on K8s Cluster "https://spiffe.io/docs/latest/try/getting-started-k8s/"

One of the steps in this process is running the command "kubectl apply -f client-deployment.yaml" which deploys spiffe client agent.

But the pods keeps on getting in the error state

`Error: failed to create containerd task: failed to create shim task: OCI runtime create failed: runc create failed: unable to start container process: exec: "sleep": executable file not found in $PATH: unknown`

Image used : ghcr.io/spiffe/spire-agent:1.5.1

Comment: Your Kubernetes cluster is minikube or cloud or ...?

Comment: Try this similar [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72639049/oci-runtime-create-failed-runc-create-failed-unable-to-start-container-process) may help to resolve your issue.

Comment: Cluster is AWS EKS

Comment: @VeeraNagireddy Its not related to that anyhow

Answer (score 1):

It seems connected to [this PR](https://github.com/spiffe/spire-tutorials/pull/98) from 3 days ago (there is no longer a "sleep" executable in the image).

> SPIRE is moving away from the alpine Docker release images in favor of scratch images that contain only the release binary to minimize the size of the images and include only the software that is necessary to run in the container.

You should report the issue and use

> gcr.io/spiffe-io/spire-agent:1.2.3

(the last image they used) meanwhile.

Comment: It seems the issue is also present in image 1.5.0. Simply changed the deployment file to 1.5.0 still same error

Comment: You are right, the last image they used was: gcr.io/spiffe-io/spire-agent:1.2.3
(as seen in the PR)